# Spring MVC model doesn't know my class

Tags: java, spring, model-view-controller, model

I have a problem that should be straight forward and I'm clearly doing something wrong.
I have a simple site written in Spring MVC. My JSP model doesn't know my NewItem class..

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String newsFeed(Model model) {       
    try {
        initDB();
    } catch (Exception e) {     
        e.printStackTrace();
    }   

    ScanRequest scanRequest = new ScanRequest()
    .withTableName("Table1");
    ScanResult result = _database.get(scanRequest);         
    //This will just return a list with filled NewsItems from the database  
    List<NewsItem> list = getNewsItems(result.getItems());      
    model.addAttribute("newsList",list);        
    return "newsfeed";
}

public class NewsItem  {    
    private String url="";
    String getUrl(){
        return url;
    }
    void setUrl(String text) {
        url = text;
    }
    private String title="";
    void setTitle(String text) {
        title = text;
        Image = text;
    }

    String getTitle(){
        return title;
    }   
    String Description="";    
    String Image="";
    String Time="";
    String Since="";
}
```

> And when im using ${newsList.getTile()} on the JSP side im getting a
>   javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: javax.el.MethodNotFoundException:
>   Method not found: class java.util.ArrayList.getTile() or
>   java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string:.. when Im trying to
>   use ${newsList.Image}. Does anyone know what Im missing here?
>
> stuff im using in jsp. taglib uri="http://tiles.apache.org/tags-tiles"
>   prefix="tiles"  taglib prefix="spring"
>   uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" taglib
>   uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" page
>   import="com.kiiak.tennman.NewsItem"

Answer (score 2):

Call `getTitle` (note spelling)  on a `NewsItem` rather than on the `List` itself

```
<c:forEach var="newsItem" items="${newsList}">
    ${newsItem.title}
</c:forEach>
```

Comment: That's the answer I think.

Comment: HI, thx for your anwser. Now I’m getting the same exceptions but the exception is point to the correct class and not ArrayList.. Property 'title' not found. If im trying getTitle() no method found in class com.x.y.NewsItem., do I need to register the class or inherent some kind of interface to get it work?

Comment: `getTitle` (and all other bean methods) should be `public`